# oVirt or Proxmox with Cloudstack

Tags: kvm-virtualization, proxmox, ovirt, cloudstack

I am using a cloud infrastructure based on XenServer and orchestrated by Cloudstack for lab purposes, and I want to try another KVM hypervisor on the same cloud. Is it possible to use oVirt or Proxmox along with Cloudstack? I mean.. is oVirt/Proxmox similar to XenCenter and able to cooperate with Cloudstack?

Comment: I can't tell if oVirt or Proxmox can co-operate with Cloudstack. But you can surely use plain KVM - libvirt hypervisors.

Comment: I think it would be easier for OP to install CentOS or Ubuntu with KVM and manage it with Cloudstack. I've been testing it with CentOS7 KVM environment.

Answer (score 1):

CloudStack has native support for KVM, you don't need any additional component such as oVirt or Proxmox. You can deploy/setup new KVM hosts and add them to a new KVM-based cluster in CloudStack. See http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/installguide/hypervisor/kvm.html and http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/adminguide/hosts.html

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/4.14.0.0/conceptsandterminology/concepts.html#what-can-apache-cloudstack-do says oVirt and Proxmox are both not on the list.

If you are willing to explore other management options, you could try ManageIQ - it supports oVirt, Openstack VMWare, k8s and a bunch of other platforms (No Xen though)